# node-soap 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' error

Tags: node.js, web-services, ssl, soap, wsdl

Im trying to access WSDL methods by SSL with node-soap module. I can connect to the server and get `client.desclibe()`, but when I'm trying to access method on WSDL, i get :

```
authorized: false,
authorizationError: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
```

I tried to disable SSL verification or use `ssl-root-cas` module, but it doesnt make a sence, every time i getting this error.

This is how im using `node-soap`:

```
client = soap.createClient(wsdl_url, {
        wsdl_options: {
                key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/privatekey.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/public-certificate.crt'),
                passphrase: 'password',
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            },
        forceSoap12Headers: true
    },
    function(err, client){

        client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
                'ssl/privatekey.key' , 
                'ssl/public-certificate.crt' , 
                'ssl/new-ca.crt' ,
                {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false,
                    passphrase: 'password'
                }

    ));

    client.ServerMethod({ name : 'value' }, function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
    });
})
```

Anyone has suggestions what's going wrong? I need SSL up, so i cant just switch it off.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

Can you try something like this before your soap call ?

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

Hope it helps.